# How to center xymatrix with respect to logical center?

Tags: positioning, xy-pic

I have an `\xymatrix` with 4 rows and 2 columns. I want to center it horizontally. I used `\centerline{}` but it (of course) just centers the whole box created by `\xymatrix`.

Since my matrix entries are textual and one of them is wider that others, centering whole box doesn't seem right. I would like to center it with respect to the center of the matrix rather than with respect to the center of produced box. Is it possible?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
    \hrule
    \centerline{\xymatrix{
        \txt{short} \ar[d] \ar[r] & \txt{short} \ar[d] \\
        \txt{long long long long long} \ar[d] \ar[r] & \txt{short} \ar[d] \\
        \txt{short} \ar[r] & \txt{short}
    }}
    \hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What is the center of the matrix for you? For me I understand it as the center of the box created by `\xymatrix{}`.

Comment: @Sigur: By horizontal center of a matrix with two columns I mean the average of centers of the columns. I mean the center of the grid of the matrix when you imagine just points instead of actual contents of the elements.

Comment: @user87690, see if this can help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154662/14757

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid this can not be done from within the `\xymatrix` and requires to make some calculations.

So, we load the `calc` package and calculate the horizontal spacing that has to be added to achieve what you want:

```
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{(\widthof{long long long long long}-\widthof{short})/2}
```

Then we add an `\hspace*{\mylength}` to move the `\xymatrix` in the desired position.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{(\widthof{long long long long long}-\widthof{short})/2}

\begin{document}
    \hrule
    \centerline{\xymatrix{
        \txt{short} \ar[d] \ar[r] & \txt{short} \ar[d] \\
        \txt{long long long long long} \ar[d] \ar[r] & \txt{short} \ar[d] \\
        \txt{short} \ar[r] & \txt{short}
    }\hspace*{\mylength}}
    \hrule
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to calculate the \mylength in a way like <position of center of the matrix from left of the produce box> * 2 - \widthof{\xymatrix{…}} so we don't rely on particular content of the elements?

Comment: @user87690 I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
    \hrule
    \centerline{\xymatrix{%
        \txt{short} \ar[d] \ar[r] & \txt{short} \ar[d] \\
        \txt{\makebox[2em][r]{long long long long long}} \ar[d] \ar[r] & \txt{short} \ar[d] \\
        \txt{short} \ar[r] & \txt{short}
    }}
    \hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Straight and Simple. Just use `\centerline`. Super-liked this one! It successfully horizontally centre-aligned my commutative diagrams!